# OpenGL: VAO/VBO confusion

Tags: c++, opengl, vbo, vao

The [OpenGL Wiki: Vertex Specification](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Vertex_Specification) states that:

> **Note:** The `GL_ARRAY_BUFFER`​ binding is **NOT** part of the VAO's state! I know that's confusing, but that's the way it is.

Below is how I use the VAO, which seems to work as intended. What is wrong here? My understanding of OpenGL (or OpenGL Wiki), my OpenGL driver (OSX 10.9) or the OpenGL Wiki?

```
// ------ Pseudo-code ------ 
// setup
[...]
glBindVertexArray(vertexArrayObjectIdx1);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBufferId1);
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, elementBufferId1);
for each vertex attribute
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(...);
    glVertexAttribPointer(...);

glBindVertexArray(vertexArrayObjectIdx2);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBufferId2);
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, elementBufferId2);
for each vertex attribute
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(...);
    glVertexAttribPointer(...);

// rendering
[...]
glBindVertexArray(vertexArrayObjectIdx1);
glDrawElements(...);
glBindVertexArray(vertexArrayObjectIdx2);
glDrawElements(...);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It means that when you rebind the `VAO` the `GL_ARRAY_BUFFER` does not get rebound

However the `glVertexAttribPointer` does bind the (then) bound `GL_ARRAY_BUFFER` to the correct attribute in the VAO so it does work like you want.

Actually they could have defined `glVertexAttribPointer` as:

```
void glVertexAttribPointer(GLuint index​, GLint size​, GLenum type​, GLboolean normalized​, GLsizei stride​, uint bufferName, const GLvoid * pointer​);
```

and eliminate it's dependency on the bound `GL_ARRAY_BUFFER`. But hindsight and all that...

Important to remember is that the `GL_ARRAY_BUFFER` is not important to drawing but the how the vertex attributes are bound is.

in contrast the `GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER` *is* stored in the VAO

Comment: There is actually a version of `glVertexAttribPointer (...)` with roughly that signature. But you have to use the [Direct State Access](http://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/EXT/direct_state_access.txt) extension (which basically rules out Apple, Intel and Mesa implementations and leaves only AMD and NV). It is ***very*** awkward to wrap you head around at first (mostly because of the function name), but this ugly mess of a function: `glVertexArrayVertexAttribOffsetEXT (...)` will let you setup a pointer to a VBO's data store to a VAO at a specific index without binding either the VBO or VAO.

Comment: That said, they really could not have defined `glVertexAttribPointer (...)` that way, because this function was introduced to OpenGL with the ARB Vertex Program extension. And ARBVP1 can be implemented in the absence of Vertex Buffer Objects (ARBVP1 pre-dates VBOs by 2-3 years).

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman don't deny that if they could redesign from scratch then they would lessen the reliance on global state so much

Comment: Of course it would. I was just pointing out that `glVertexAttribPointer (...)` was not designed that way originally because VBOs did not exist when shaders were first introduced into OpenGL. Long's Peak would have made OpenGL a much nicer API, but about all we have left of it is the DSA extension, which is not supported widely :(

Answer (score 1):

Down below in the same Wiki entry, you can see the explanation as well - `This is also why GL_ARRAY_BUFFER​ is not VAO state; the actual association between an attribute index and a buffer is made by glVertexAttribPointer​.` ...